# Where did the notification bar for receiving a badge go?

Tags: support, badges, notification-bar

I was getting a notification bar if I received any badge.

But I have noticed that I didn't see any notification bar for the last 2-3 badges, including:

1. Constituent
2. Sportsmanship

Where did bar of notification for receiving badges go?

Comment: You should have gotten a notification _alert_ on the collider, is that where you're talking about?

Comment: This behavior recently changed from the previous big-orange-slidy notification to a subtler notification.  See here: [Revamped Notifications](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/revamped-notifications/)

Comment: Yes saw now. There are notifications about badges received. But I was getting notification bar when I received any badge. And having message "You received xyz badge". I am talking about that. Is that feature removed?

Comment: Just read the blog post linked by @jadarnel27. In short: Yes, if you mean the presentation; no, if you mean getting notified.

Comment: Oh no...This notifications are shown in white colour. And it is not getting attention. I was loving that notification bar.

Comment: I liked the orange bar and how they stacked, only because I imagined them filling Jon Skeet's entire screen.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are looking at this place on the page for that information, right?

[image: image demonstrating correct location]

Sorry if my choice of image capturing tool blinds some of you with overlay text :p

See: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/revamped-notifications/

Thanks to [@jadarnel27](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/168428/jadarnel27) for pointing out the URL on the blog post for me.

Comment: I was getting notification bar when I received any badge. And having message "You received xyz badge". I am talking about that. Is that feature removed?

Comment: I am pretty sure this feature supplants that feature.

Comment: No problem, sir =)

Answer (score 11):

From [this blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/05/21/revamped-notifications/), it indicates the orange bar notifying you of your recent badges has been removed.

You can still see all your notifications (including badges) by clicking on the global notification icon and then selecting the notifications option.
[image: gni]
<sub>(source: [stackoverflow.com](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/clicky.png))</sub>

If you want to view your most recent badges, you can click on the arrow next to your name to display your recent stats. Any badges you've received recently will be indicated at the bottom of the window (*see highlight*).
[image: notifications 2]